# Finite group representation as $\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma)$ action $H^1(\Gamma,\mathbb{Z})$ of graph?

Tags: graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, group-cohomology

Let $\Gamma$ be a finite graph, then $H^1(\Gamma,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}^{g(\Gamma)}$ can be viewed as a $\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma)$ module.

Conversely, given a finite group $G$, and a $G$-module $\mathbb{Z}^n$, does there always exist a finite graph $\Gamma$ such that the $G$ module $\mathbb{Z}^n$ arises as $G\overset{f}{\to}\mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma)\curvearrowright H^1(\Gamma,\mathbb{Z})$ for some $f\colon G\to \mathrm{Aut}(\Gamma)$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. An action of a group $G$ on a graph $\Gamma$ induces a homomorphism $G\to \mathrm{Out}(\pi_1(\Gamma))=\mathrm{Out}(F_n)$. So a representation $G\to \mathrm{GL}_n({\mathbb Z})$ can come from an action on a graph only if it lifts to a homomorphism $G\to \mathrm{Out}(F_n)$ over the quotient homomorphism $\mathrm{Out}(F_n)\to \mathrm{GL}_n({\mathbb Z})$. [This paper of Zimmermann](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604464.pdf) gives an example of a finite cyclic subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n({\mathbb Z})$ that does not lift.

Comment: How do you define "an action by outer automorphisms" for a group action on another group?

Comment: What you mean is correct; it's just that it sounded weird to me to call this an "action by outer automorphisms" (note that what you say in your comment does not make use of the group structure of $G$). Possibly by outer action of $G$ on a group $H$ one can just mean a homomorphism $G\to\mathrm{Out}(H)$.

Comment: I'll just throw in that this terminology, however imprecise, is nonetheless pretty well established in group theory.

Comment: Anyhow, I edited.

Comment: More precisely the linked paper gives finite cyclic subgroups which do not lift, for every $n\ge 3$. For $n\le 2$ the quotient homomorphism is an isomorphism and hence lifting holds.

Comment: However, for $n=2$ it seems that the automorphism group of a leafless finite connected graph with fundamental group $F_2$ can only be of order 1, 2, 4 or 8, and hence we miss cyclic subgroups of order 3 (adding leaves can increase the order of the automorphism group but will not change the action on homology). In general, this suggests that "most" finite subgroups of $\mathrm{Out}(F_n)$ can't be realized by an action on a graph.

Comment: @YCor: It's a theorem, proved independently by Culler, by Zimmerman, and by Khramstov, that every finite subgroup of $\text{Out}(F_n)$ can be realized by an action on a graph. For example the order 3 cyclic group acts on the rank 2 theta graph.

Comment: @LeeMosher Oops, I had a mistaken argument in mind. Indeed, the graph consisting of 2 vertices with 2 edges joining them (or its barycentric subdivision if one wants to forbid multi-edges) has an automorphism group with elements of order 3. Thanks for the correction and mentioning this theorem.